# react redux - applying a "fetch" and dispatch inside of a dispatch fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a working action that saves a JWT token with the simple call "saveJwt(data)".

Here is the action:

```
export const requestLoginToken = (username, password) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({type: REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: username})

    const payload = {
      userName: username,
      password: password,
    }

    const task = fetch('/api/jwt', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
    })
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({type: RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: data})
        saveJwt(data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        clearJwt()
        dispatch({type: ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: error.message})
      })
    addTask(task)
    return task
  }
```

I then added in just under "saveJwt(data)" This block of code:

```
    if (!confirmSelectDataExistance()) {
      dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })
      const token = getJwt()
      const headers = new Headers({
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      })
      const retrieveSelectData = fetch('/api/SelectData/SelectData', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        },
      })
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(selectData => {
          dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: selectData })
          saveSelectData(selectData)
        })
   }
```

All it is suppose to do is check if items are in local storage and if so do another fetch this time with the JWT added.

Here is the completed action so you can see where it sits:

```
export const requestLoginToken = (username, password) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: username })

    const payload = {
      userName: username,
      password: password,
    }

    const task = fetch('/api/jwt', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
    })
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: data })
        saveJwt(data)
        //selectData download if nothing is local storage.
        if (!confirmSelectDataExistance()) {
          dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })
          const token = getJwt()
          const headers = new Headers({
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
          })
          const retrieveSelectData = fetch('/api/SelectData/SelectData', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
          })
            .then(handleErrors)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(selectData => {
              dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: selectData })
              saveSelectData(selectData)
            })
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        clearJwt()
        dispatch({ type: ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: error.message })
      })
    addTask(task)
    return task
  }
```

So now my first fetch ends up with an undefined promise and it simply jumps down to the bottom with undefined for the value of task,,

Would you believe yesterday it was working perfectly and when I tried it today its failing.

Why does that code block cause the whole thing to fail.. I comment it out and it works fine..

I am suspecting that its to do with two promises etc but there must be a correct way to manage this.. I would have thought that if it was going off to save the JWT token that that would indicate its finished with the first download however something else is wrong... in that block of code or more likely the way its been used.

Comment: Do you mean promise 'task' returns something in the first case or returns undefined value in the second (after update)? 
I am not sure I understand your problem but I suspect returning retrieveSelectData from corresponding function might be a solution

Comment: Wondering if you might expand on this if you could.. @Igor

Comment: Again, I am not sure what IS the problem for you but generally speaking if you expect anywhere that requestLoginToken resolves after retrieveSelectData  resolves it requires chaining of the later to the prior. 
The way it is implemented now promise retrieveSelectData executes in a maner similar to 'fire and forget' and the only thing that makes you aware of it completion is action RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA

Comment: is confirmSelectDataExistance() an async function? If it return a promise, then you have to wait until it return data.

Comment: @Igor I believe you are right about this... confirmSelectDataExistance()  has no promise attached. it just checks if something is in localStorage. How do you chain a conditional statement and run it if it is true?

Comment: If you return a promise from function in than it will be chained.
I wonder if confirmSelectDataExistance returns promise self. If it is you mist call it like confirmSelectDataExistance(). than(trueOrFalse => {if (trueOrFalse) {fetch}})

Comment: Sorry but I am having trouble with how to write that syntax. .then(confirmSelectDataExistance()) => ??

Comment: I'll post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that confirmSelectDataExistance is async and returns promise and that promise retrieveSelectData must be resolved prior to requestLoginToken the solution might be:

```
export const requestLoginToken = (username, password) =>
(dispatch, getState) => {
   dispatch({ type: REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: username })

   const payload = {
     userName: username,
     password: password,
   }

const task = fetch('/api/jwt', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
  },
})
  .then(handleErrors)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: data })
    saveJwt(data)
    //selectData download if nothing is local storage.

    return confirmSelectDataExistance().then(isConfirmed => {
      if (!isConfirmed) {
        dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })
        const token = getJwt()
        const headers = new Headers({
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        })
        const retrieveSelectData = fetch('/api/SelectData/SelectData', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
          },
        })
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(selectData => {
          dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: selectData })
          saveSelectData(selectData)
        });

        return retrieveSelectData;
      }
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    clearJwt()
    dispatch({ type: ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: error.message })
  })
addTask(task)
return task
}
```

If saveSelectData is also async you should call instead

```
 return saveSelectData(selectData);
```